# Как изменить картинки по клику?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Дорогие друзья, Я хочу сделать чтобы при клике картинка изменилась. Как мне этого добиться через JS или jQuery?

Вот мой `HTML`:

```
    <a id='js-mnu' class='js-mnu'></a>
    <a id='js-cross' class='js-cross'></a>
```

Вот мой `CSS`:

```
#js-mnu {display:block;display:block;width:35px;height:35px;margin:17px 10px;float:right;}
#js-cross{display:block;display:block;width:35px;height:35px;margin:17px  10px;float:right;}
.js-mnu {background:url(images/mnu.png) center center no-repeat;opacity:0.75;}
.js-cross{background:url(images/cross-grey.png) center center no-repeat; opacity: 0.75;}
```

Comment: измемилась или заменилась на другую?

Comment: @codename0082016 чтобы заменилась на другую, т.е. я хочу добиться того, что при клике на картинку `js-mnu`, у меня она скрывалась и появлялась картинка `js-cross`.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
        .redButton > div
        {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/u1SbuRE.png');
        }
        .redButton.Down > div
        {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/vi1KLp9.png');
        }
        .link > div
        {
            width: 88px;
            height: 88px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $(".link").click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();

             var mainButton = $(e.target).parent();

             $('.link').not(mainButton).removeClass('Down');  

             mainButton.toggleClass('Down');
             $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');    
             $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');        
             });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <a class="link redButton" href="#" data-rel="content1">
        <div></div>
        </a>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    </div>
```

**[jsFiddle Hot Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thcP5/)**

Можете убрать `$('.link').not(mainButton).removeClass('Down');` тогда прошлая картинка не будет возвращаться при клике на следующую

**Вариант 2 но здесь без CSS**

```
<script>
    function change() {
   var img1 = "http://placehold.it/350x150",
       img2 = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
   var imgElement = document.getElementById('test');

   imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
}
</script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="test" onclick ="change();"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/s8qLg7ur/